# Create new groupings based on the String element of a Map<String, List<Object>>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of `Objects` named `Coordinates` and each Coordinate contains three values. Two of type `double` x, y and one `String` name. My code receives as input entries of Coordinates and groups them based on the name by creating a `Map` of type `<String, List<Object>>`. In this way instead of having pairs of coordinates associated with a name, I have a name that associates to all the corresponding coordinates.

E.G. :

Before Map:

```
[0.01,0.51] --> A
[0.01,0.56] --> A
[0.01,0.61] --> A
[0.01,0.66] --> AB
[0.01,0.71] --> ABC
[0.01,0.76] --> ABC
```

where A, B and C are the names. If multiple names appear together means that they share the same coordinates.

After Map:

```
[[0.01,0.01,0.01],[0.51,0.56,0.61]] --> A
[[0.01,0.01], [0.61,0.66]]          --> AB
[[0.01, 0.01], [0.71,0.76]]         --> ABC
```

What I would like to achieve is to separate each name from the group and link all the coordinates to that name.

E.G. of what I am trying to achieve:

```
[[0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01],[0.51,0.56,0.61,0.66,0.71,0.76]] --> A
[[0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01], [0.61,0.66,0.71,0.76]]                    --> B
[[0.01,0.01], [0.71,0.76]]                                        --> C
```

The code that creates the `Map` and groups them by name is the following:

```
Map<String, List<Coordinates>> newList = coordinateList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Coordinates::getName));
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Note that the names, e.g. ABC, are not separated by commas or spaces but if it helps with a possible solution I already know how to do this (A,B,C).

Coordinates class:

```
public class Coordinates {
    private double X;
    private double Y;
    private String name;

    public Coordinates(double dexp, double dent, String name) {
        this.X=dexp;
        this.Y=dent;
        this.name=name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "["+X+","+Y+"]";
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getX() {
        return X;
    }
    public void setX(double x) {
        X = x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return Y;
    }
    public void setY(double y) {
        Y = y;
    }

}
```

Example of names:

```
STEP(One)
STEP(Two)
STEP(One)STEP(Two)
```

Comment: So all your names are single-letters? Otherwise there has to be a way to separate the individual names.

Comment: No they are not single letters I just added them like that for simplicity in the example. They can contain letters, characters but not numbers.

Comment: So, we don't know what they look like and how to separate them. Also, the `Coordinates` class is not included in your question. It appears that when you split the names you also need to change the name attribute in the coordinate object itself. Without the source, we can't know if that's possible. Please [edit] your question and add both those pieces of information, otherwise I don't see how we can help you.

Comment: I am circumspect about the choice to use `double` values as identifiers.  The value 0.1 cannot be exactly represented as a double precision floating point value in Java.  The choice to use doubles as identifiers may make your system fragile and error-prone.

Answer (score -1):

if I'm understanding you correctly, we'll presume you can already reach your second map easily. This should work for either map however and you could even optimize it slightly based on that. Going forward with this assumption and using your `Map<String, List<Coordinate>>`, we can accumulate/merge based on that input:

```
Map<String, List<Coordinate>> myComboMap = /* ... */;
Map<String, List<Coordinate>> myAbsoluteMap = new HashMap<>();
myComboMap.forEach((name, coords) -> {
    List<String> names = /* split up name into list, or just iterate */;
    names.forEach(n -> {
        //merge or create the results for each name
        myAbsoluteMap.compute(n, (key, old) -> {
            if (old == null) {
                //copy list to avoid changing old map
                return new ArrayList<>(coords);
            }
            //or append to an existing list
            old.addAll(coords);
            return old;
        });
    });
});
```

This can also be done with streams via #flatMap and Collectors#toMap, however that solution will involve the creation of quite a few objects, so I went with a side-effect #forEach for simplicity.

**Note**: This will create a map of single-names to their respective coordinates. You can flip that map quite easily (both should be fairly unique), though I'm not certain of the use-case myself. Keep in mind if two names have the same coordinates on this map, then flipping the map could result in losing one of those names. Thus I left the answer as-is with names->coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

Leaving the name splitting task for you and assuming you dont want to create a new `Coordinate` object with the split name, you can do this:

```
   Map<String, List<Coordinates> > newList = coordinateList.stream()
       .flatMap( c -> split( c.getName() ).stream()
                      .map( sn -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(sn, c) ) )
       .collect( Collectors.groupingBy(
                 Map.Entry::getKey, 
                 Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList() ) ) );
```